# creating a login component which will show login error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a login component which will show login error.
But I don't know how to bring `errors` array from `_onSubmit` function to `LoginForm`

Here my code the code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Split from 'grommet/components/Split';
import Section from 'grommet/components/Section';
import Sidebar from 'grommet/components/Sidebar';
import LoginForm from 'grommet/components/LoginForm';
//import Logo from './Logo';
import firebase from 'firebase';
export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._onSubmit = this._onSubmit.bind(this);
    this._onResponsive = this._onResponsive.bind(this);
    this.state = {responsive: 'multiple',errors:[]};
  }

  _onSubmit(fields) {


    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(fields.username, fields.password).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      var errors = [];

      errors.push(errorCode);
      errors.push(errorMessage);
      console.log(errors);


      // How to bring the errors from here to ??????
    });
  }

  _onResponsive(responsive) {
    this.setState({responsive: responsive});
  }

  render() {

    var image;
    if ('multiple' === this.state.responsive) {
      image = <Section full={true} pad="none" texture="url(img/grafitti.jpg)" />;
    }


    return (
      <Split flex="left" separator={true} onResponsive={this._onResponsive}>
        {image}
        <Sidebar justify="center" align="center" pad="medium" size="large">
          <LoginForm

            title="Ferret"
            onSubmit={this._onSubmit}
            errors={??????} />
        </Sidebar>
      </Split>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anybody give a guide? Thanks!!!

Comment: What programming laguage is this?

Comment: This is not a good arquitecture, think about use Redux instead, to dispatch actions from the presentational components to update the application state in the store executing async actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are creating closure when you introduce the function within the .catch() handler.

You are correctly binding your `this` to the `_onSubmit` function, but from within the closure you created with the `function() {}`, your `this` is not bound to the outer scope.

You have the option of using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which does not create a lexical this:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(fields.username, fields.password)
  .catch((error) => {
    ...
    // Now works since the arrow function does not create a new lexical this
    this.setState({})
  });
```

or, you can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) your outer `this` (the one you are expecting to have a `setState()` function) to the inner closure:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(fields.username, fields.password)
  .catch(function(error) {
    this.setState({}) // Is now bound to the outer this
  }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Anytime!  All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Just pass state.errors to your child component as props.

```
<LoginForm
        title="Ferret"
        onSubmit={this._onSubmit}
        errors={this.state.errors} />
```

Make sure in LoginForm you don't display errors when the value passed is an empty array.

Comment: When there is an error, I think I need to setState inside function _onSubmit like: this.setState({errors: errors}). But I got error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: I think it's because you are passing function(error) inside the catch block. Try and use an arrow function like this .catch((error) => {code goes here and this.setState}). Basically, you are doing this.setState inside this block of code where this doesn't refer to the class anymore. I think another way is to do fucntion(error, this) but I'm not sure